# SAP HANA - SQL - calculate columns on the same table without recursive functions

Tags: hana

I have the following simple table with approx. 40k items:

```
|date|consum|
```

Based on this table, I want to calculate some new columns. At the end, the table should look like:

```
|date|consum|row|row_relativ|min|max|upper|lower|
```

Unfortunately the SAP HANA Database does not support recursive table statements...

Here are the calculation rules:

1. row = `row_number() over(order by dates)`
2. row_relative = `row*35040/32768`
3. min = `floor(row_relative)`
4. max = `ceil(row_relative)`
5. min = select the consum from the row with the min value
6. max = select the consum from the row with the max value

At the moment I have a stored procedure with 5 variables. In each variable I calculate 1 new column. It is very very dirty... How can I make it different? I can't use recursive functions... :/

Here is my SQL snippet... have fun =)

```
var1 = select *, row_number() over(order by dates) as row from XYZ order by dates limit 34944;
var2 = select *, (row * 34944/32768) as row_relative from :var1;
var3 = select *, floor(row_relative) as min, ceil(row_relative) as max from :var2;

var4 = select 
    p.*,
    (select consumfrom :var3 where row = p.min) as lower,
    (select consumfrom :var3 where row = p.max) as upper
from :var3 p;

var5 = select 
    p.*,
    (p.lower* (1-p.row_relative+p.min)+p.upper * (p.row_relativ - p.min)) as new_consum
from :var4 p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following CTE Common Table Expression in your SQLScript 
BTW, it is very interesting that nearly the same [SQL Server CTE](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) syntax matches the SAP HANA SQLScript syntax :)

```
with cte as (
select
    date,
    consum,
    row_number() over (order by date) as row
from rawdata
)
select
    date,
    consum,
    row,
    row * 35040 / 32768 as row_relative,
    floor( (row * 35040 / 32768) ) as min,
    ceil( (row * 35040 / 32768) ) as max,
    (select cte2.consum from cte cte2 where row = floor( (cte.row * 35040 / 32768) ) ) as min2,
    (select cte2.consum from cte cte2 where row = ceil( (cte.row * 35040 / 32768) ) ) as max2
from cte
```

Comment: The reason why the HANA CTE matches the SQL Server CTE syntax is not a surprise. Because the syntax for common table expressions are defined in the SQL standard, not by "SQL Server" (and Microsoft did ignore the standard to a certain extent there). They are **not** something Microsoft invented. And other DBMS had them long before Microsoft even thought about adding them